# Get Scrollview from MKMapView

Tags: uiscrollview, mkmapview

Im trying to get the scrollview from MKMapView but it returns MKScrollContainerView instead of UIScrollView. I am trying to do this in ios6 and ios7. Does anybody know how I can access that scrollbar.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Which scrollbar are you talking about? I'm looking at iOS 6 and I've never seen any scroll bars in a map view.

Comment: i meant scrollview -->> UIScrollView * scroll = [[[[mapView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];